# list of devices supports instant Apps

Tags: android, google-play, android-instant-apps

I want to know the list of devices which supports instant apps. In android documentation they have mentioned android version 6 and higher will support instant apps.

I have tested in some of devices its working fine. but some other devices its opened in browser.(https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasty,https://abdcoop.mybuzztm.com/pub/abudhabicoop) . but the failed devices also has the setting -Google Settings -> instant Apps options enabled.

while testing Instant Apps worked on these devices.

Samsung s6 Note -> 7.1.1

Moto g4 Plus -> 7.1.1

OnePlus 3 -> Oxygen 7.1.1

Comment: is this a question? Doesn't look like one

Comment: @TimCastelijns there is no specific info about the list of devices supports instant apps.the documentation says it supports 6.0 and higher , i have tested 3 devices with 6.0.1 which fails to invoke instant app.so i thought of adding this question.

Comment: what question? "create a list" is not a question

Comment: @TimCastelijns i have edited the question..

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is a comprehensive list that's publicly available yet. For now, you just have to make sure your Chrome, Google Play Store, and Google Play Services are up-to-date, then restart your device. Shortly afterwards, if your OEM has integrated IA-support for your device, it will download the Instant Apps supervisor and be visible in Google Settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive list of devices. [The FAQ](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html) state on that topic:

> - **What devices are supported for Android Instant Apps?**
>
>   Android Instant Apps are available on the majority of devices running 
>     Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher.